# getting coordinates of a visual block via Neovim python API

Tags: neovim, neovim-python-client

*(This is a copy of my original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435330/getting-coordinates-of-a-visual-block-via-neovim-api) on stackoverflow)*

Hi!

I am browsing through the list of available functions in Neovim Python Client API in search of a way to get coordinates of a **current** visual mode selection. Something that would give me a pair of (row #,column #) of a visual block start/end.

I have tried using the vim native getpos function in the following way (suggested in a comment to the original question):

```
from neovim import attach

nvim = attach('child', argv=["/bin/env","nvim","--embed"])
buffer = nvim.current.buffer
buffer[0] = 'visual mode' 
nvim.feedkeys("fmve")
print("Current caret position: {}".format(nvim.windows[0].cursor))
cmd ='getpos("\'<")' # cmd=r"""getpos("'<")"""
print("Start of visual selection: {}".format(nvim.eval(cmd)))
```

The issue with the using "'<" mark is that i need to leave the visual mode to get the coordinates, so a call to `feedkeys` needs to become:

```
nvim.feedkeys("fmve<Esc>")
```

while my task requires staying in the visual mode.  Is there another recipe?

Thanks

Comment: @user852573, I am not sure why you removed you comment.
Indeed the marks are being set after modify feedkeys argument to "fmve<Esc>".  This doesn't help me achieve what i need: visual selection bounds while still in visual mode.  I will edit the quesiton to be more explicit.

Comment: If you're ok with temporarily leaving visual mode, then maybe you could escape so that Vim sets the mark, then reselect with `gv`: `nvim.feedkeys("fmve\egv")` (here `\e` stands for the `Escape` key). Also, if the `feedkeys()` function you invoke accepts flags, try to pass to it the `n` flag (to prevent recursive mappings), and maybe `i` (to `i`nsert the keys in the typeahead buffer instead of `a`ppending them): `nvim.feedkeys("fmve\egv", "in")`

Comment: hm...  this is more complicated than what i was counting on.  But if there is no other way than leaving visual mode to only get right back into it, i guess i will have to make do.  Thanks!